# real escape string and mysqli prepare statement conflict

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm using real escape string and prepared statement in mysqli in that case Ii face a problem when am giving input single quote it saved in database as

```
"  \'   "
```

My code is:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test1');

if($db->connect_errno > 0)
{
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');

}
$s="a'a";
$s=$db->real_escape_string($s); 
$sql="insert into table1 values(?,?)";
$id="";
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$id,$s);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->errno)
{
    echo $stmt->error;
}
else
{
    echo "inserted successfully";
}
```

Inserted value is `id=0` and `val=a\'a`.

So how can I validate my user input?

Comment: You don't need `real_escape_string()` with prepared statements. That's kinda the point of prepared statements.

Comment: The whole point of prepared statements is that you don't have to escape things. It works like magic and auto-escapes everything as required. You don't need `real_escape_string` any more. Remove it.

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde. Is prepare statement only enough for user input sanitize like html element, other drop code, backslashes etc...

Comment: It protects your database from SQL injections but does not prevent XSS and other web based attacks. You still need to do your due diligence when handling user provided data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `real escape string` if you are using prepared statement. If you are using prepared statement strings are escaped automatically.
One advice: always use prepared statement instead of trivial method which involves use of `real_escape_string`

Comment: This is not a thing. I just tested a 'JavaScript' injection on a prepared insert statement and it worked! The JavaScript fired!

Comment: @Warwick I did not say anything about injection, I just said real_escape_string is better than traditional method.

Comment: @ιηςπεδιδιεζαυπαυ you can visit this page to get example http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#refsect1-mysqli.real-escape-string-examples

Comment: sorry @edwardtorvalds, that comment was not for you. I mistyped it on this answer.